# Node.js sending HTTP requests from specified port

Tags: node.js, http

I would like to send HTTP requests using the request module, but I want to specify from which port he will make the request, not just which port it will send it to. Is it possible, and if so how?

Edit: It wasn't explained properly, I want to have a few instances of the same program, that will talk to each other sometimes (mostly not), so I'm wondering is there anyway that they could listen and send requests from a port of my choosing, so each of them will have unique port to live on.

Comment: Why would you want that? A client's source port is almost never of any interest.

Comment: I'm testing some design in node, that will make multiple instances of itself on different port and sometimes they'll need to talk to each other, so I want each of them to sent requests from different ports

Comment: That already happens by the TCP/IP stack of your OS. Read: [Wikipedia: Ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).

Comment: Is it possible for them to listen on that same port they sent from the request?

Comment: Can you perhaps try to explain the problem you're trying to solve, as to not end up with an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Edited question, thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand how TCP works. If you just ignore the sending port, you will probably find your application works just fine.